# Apache rewrite to Nginx rewrite. QSA issues. How to convert properly?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I have this rule now:

```
 RewriteRule ^/mp3/(.*)$ /music/$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^/activate/(.*) /index.php?p=activate.php&hash=$1 [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&page=$2 [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&page=$2 [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

But moved to Nginx, i've created these rules, but now working, i get 404 only:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/mp3/(.*) /music/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/activate/(.*) /index.php?p=activate.php&hash=$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&page=$2 break;
    rewrite ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&page=$2 break;
    rewrite ^(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1 break;
}
```

How to convert QSA rules to Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike apache's mod_rewrite, you *can* match against the query string in nginx's `rewrite` command. So you'd want something like:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/mp3/(.*) /music/$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/activate/([^\?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php?p=activate.php&hash=$1&$2 permanent;
    rewrite ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/([^\?]*)(?:\?(.*))?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&page=$2&$3 break;
    rewrite ^(.*)/([0-9]+)(?:\?(.*))?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&page=$2&$3 break;
    rewrite ^(.*)/(?:\?(.*))?$ index.php?p=$1&$2 break;
}
```

Comment: With my code index was working, but i now get 404 for the index too :S